# Настройка генератора gii

Tags: yii, url, config, gii

Скачал шаблон yii(Basic) без composer, как настроить файлы config, чтобы можно было зайти в генератор gii.

Код с файла web.php:

```
<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');
$db = require(__DIR__ . '/db.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'language' => 'ru-Ru',
    'defaultRoute' => 'category/index',
    'modules' => [
        'admin'=> [
            'class' => 'app\modules\admin\Module',
            'layout' => 'admin',
            'defaultRoute' => 'order/index',
        ],
    ],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'uvxfBK9B1S8ovnPJGbcAYyRrRCj56Qh3',
            'baseUrl' => '',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            /*'loginUrl' => 'cart/view',*/
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'smtp.mail.ru',
                'username' => 'ser588583',
                'password' => 's570224',
                'port' => '465',
                'encryption' => 'ssl',
            ],
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => $db,

        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
            //Ссылка категорий, где category наш контроллер
            'category/<id:\d+>/page/<page:\d+>' => 'category/view',
            'category/<id:\d+>' => 'category/view',
            'product/<id:\d+>' => 'product/view',
            'search' => 'category/search',
            ],
        ],

    ],
    'params' => $params,
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    ];
}

return $config;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было просто поменять вот это:

```
if (!YII_ENV_TEST) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
        'allowedIPs' => ['*'],
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
        'allowedIPs' => ['*'],
    ];
}
```

Comment: это неверно. так проблема была не в конфиге,  представленном в вопросе и не htaccess, а то, что у кого-то в индексном файле отсутствует строка `defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');`...... она нужна на `dev`..... а на продакшене не нужна, однако на продакшне не нужно и `gii`

Comment: Может быть, но так как я скинул код файла web.php , то надо было искать проблемы в этом файле.Я новичек в yii2 , надо было устанавливать через composer.